# Convert Captalize Text to dashed Text (TechnologyStackPage --> technology-stack-page ) and vice Versa (technology-stack-page --> TechnologyStackPage)

Tags: javascript

How to Write a function for converting any Captalize String into small letter dashed String and Vice Versa.
1st Example 
`TechnologyStackPage --> technology-stack-page` 
and 
`technology-stack-page --> TechnologyStackPage` 

2nd Example

`EHSCustomisedSoftwareEstimationForm --> ehs-customised-software-estimation-form`
and 
`ehs-customised-software-estimation-form --> EHSCustomisedSoftwareEstimationForm`

Comment: How can you know that `ehs` should translate to `EHS` and not `Ehs`?

Comment: I have the same concerns..

Comment: It's not possible to answer the question correctly without knowing that.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const abbr = ['EHS', 'USA']
const kebabCase = new RegExp(`(?=(?<=${abbr.join('|')}|[a-z])[A-Z]+)`, 'g')
const pascalCase = new RegExp(`(^|-)(${abbr.join('|').toLowerCase()}|[a-z])`, 'g')

console.log(``,
  'EHSCustomisedSoftwareEstimationForm'.replace(kebabCase, `-`).toLowerCase(),`\n`, 
  'CustomisedSoftwareEstimationFormUSA'.replace(kebabCase, `-`).toLowerCase(),`\n`, 
  `\n`, 
  'ehs-customised-software-estimation-form'.replace(pascalCase, (_, _1, _2) => _2.toUpperCase()),`\n`,
  'customised-software-estimation-form-usa'.replace(pascalCase, (_, _1, _2) => _2.toUpperCase())
)
```